# Divide the area of a circle in 3 equal parts starting from a point on the circle

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm asking for your help or a hint on whether there is a method to divide a circle's area in three equal parts starting the slicing by a point on the circumference of the circle.

Comment: Every way of cutting a disk involves cutting at least one point on the circumference. I think you need to be a lot more explicit about how you want these cuts to be made. Does each cut need to be a single straight line all the way across the disk and each cut have to pass through the given point on the circumference?

Comment: Yes. Each cut needs to be a straight line across the disk and each of the two cuts begins by passing through the given point on the circumference.

Comment: It may help if you edit the question to include that information. People are likely to answer (or not answer) the question based on what they read in the main part of the question without reading the comments.

Comment: It could also help if you edited the question to explain where it came from and why you are interested in it; also if you show the steps of the work you have done on it, even if it did not solve the problem, and show where you got stuck. As stated, it doesn't seem like a very attractive problem; there are no clever insights to be had as far as I can see, and no particular motivation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the point on the circumference to the origin, then calculate an angle of $120$ degrees in any direction, then slice along that angle. Slice back to the origin, repeat in the same direction as before.

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be divided into two steps.

1. Determine the center of the circle
2. Connect the center to an arbitrary point on the circle circumference. Then construct an equilateral triangle on this connection. Then construct an additional triangle on the inner edges of the triangle. This will create a 120° angle repeat the same procedure to get a 240° angle and you are done.

Comment: I am talking about slicing the circle in three equal areas, starting from the same given point located on the circumference. So I'm talking about dividing the area of the circle in three equal areas by using two slices that both start from the same point on the circumference.